# How to create variables in derived table using different conditions

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to generate a table and all the variables I need are from a derived temporary table. Now, I need to calculate the time differences under different conditions, and I need to deal with 2 questions:
1. how to create variables in derived table. 
2. how to split a variable into 2 variables using different conditions.

Please note that the sql statement I provide below is the simplified statement and please pay attention to the comments which will help you understand the question.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
Select id, name, offline_time, Process_time from 

## in the derived table, use the difference of createon in table a and b to calculte the offline_time and Process_time ##
## when {a.id = st.id AND a.activityid = 5008 and a.sessiontype = 7} a.creaton = a.creaton1 ##
## when {b.activityid = 5011} b.creaton = b.creaton1 ##

(select 
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(a.createdon)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(b.createdon))) as 'Offline_Time',
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(a.createdon1)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(b.createdon1))) as 'Process_Time',
q.id, 
q.name,
a.sessiontype
FROM tv_sessiontimer st
    LEFT JOIN sessionactivity_log a ON (a.id = st.id AND a.activityid in (5004,5008) and a.sessiontype IN (3,4,5,6,7))
    LEFT JOIN sessionactivity_log b ON (a.ssessionId = b.sessionId AND a.id = b.id AND b.activityid in (5003,5011))
    INNER JOIN tv_offline_request q ON q.id = a.sessionid
    LEFT JOIN tv_subject sub ON (sub.id = q.subjectid AND sub.SortKey > 10800 AND sub.sortkey < 30200)
    )
```